# Convert PDF to mp3

Tags: conversion, text-to-speech

- How do I convert PDF to mp3 other than the ways mentioned [here](http://www.istonsoft.com/pdf/how-do-you-convert-pdf-to-mp3-with-ease.html)?
- Is there any free software that will do this for me?
- This is because I think the read out loud feature sounds too artificial and downloading from zamzar takes long as they limit the download speed. (It's not quick)

Comment: There is may be some insight in [Good Text-to-Speech solution for Windows](http://superuser.com/q/10527/143655).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I convert PDF to mp3 other than the ways mentioned here?

You can use a program like [Dragon Dictation](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dragon-dictation/id341446764?mt=8).

> Is there any free software that will do this for me?

Adobe Reader is the free solution.  It seems all Zamzar is doing is creating a mp3 similar to the mp3 file created from the audio recording from Adobe Reader.

> This is because I think the read out loud feature sounds too artificial and downloading from zamzar takes long as they limit the download speed. (It's not quick)

Most of the "Text to Audio" voices sound artificial.  Even the voice within Nuance's $300 program sounds fake, and they are one of the leaders in that market, so you are going to have to accept artificial.

In other words...your expectations are too high.

You could also just record your own voice while you read the document.

Comment: Artificial- Not so much of a problem. But the lack of pauses make it virtually incoherent!

Comment: @Sab - It sounds like you need to record the audio yourself.

Comment: Yep . Thats is the only way I thik I can achieve it.

Comment: I recently tried the Zamzar conversion myself and found their text-to-speech is rather good compared to others I have seen. I'm just trying to figure out what their t2s recognizes to create pauses. I have software that will detect pauses to separate tracks. I'd like to use that by adding extra pauses between chapters. (fyi, I also have an audible account but some books aren't yet on audio format)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a pile of work depending on the size of your PDFs, but if you are producing the audio for "non-commercial use", the [AT&T Natural Voices Text to Speech Demo](http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php) site may help.

Copy blocks of the text from the PDF into the website, and click "SPEAK" or "DOWNLOAD".  The speaker is obviously still artificial, but some of the best artificial I've heard.

Once you download all the chunks, use something like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to assemble it.

Comment: The AT&T demo has a [paid for software available](http://www.wizzardsoftware.com/text-to-speech-tts.php) if you like the results and want to shell out a couple hundred bucks.

Comment: Looks like the online demo has a 300 character limit as well.  Working through a large PDF using the demo may not be feasible with that limitation.